# Asignación automática de tipos en Java

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente código que me da error:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String... args){
       System.out.println(Short.MAX_VALUE);
       System.out.println(Short.MIN_VALUE);
       short x = 10;
       short y = 3;
       short z = x*y;
        System.out.println(x);
    }

}
```

Cuando hago debug de la clase me aparece que las variables x e y son short.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No entiendo por qué me da error en la línea:

```
short z = x*y;
```

Estoy multiplicando dos variables short y se la asigno a otra variable short.

Gracias

Comment: A menos que quieras trabajar con números muy grandes o tengas un motivo muy claro para trabajar con short, te recomiendo usar int: es el "tipo por defecto" que usa Java y vas a tener que hacer un *casting* a cada paso si usas short

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las líneas 1 y 2 se pueden compilar porque:

**a)** Esas líneas son declaraciones de variables con inicialización de las mismas.

**b)** Todo en la expresión de inicialización es una constante en tiempo de compilación, lo que significa que toda la expresión puede evaluarse en tiempo de compilación.

Estas dos condiciones son necesarias para permitir que el compilador decida sí, está bien convertir un int en un short, porque está dentro del rango permitido. De lo contrario no es posible.

Para la línea 3, debido a que ni x ni y son constantes, el compilador no permitirá la conversión, aunque se permitió en las líneas1 y 2.

Se puede comprobar este funcionamiento modificando el código de la siguiente manera:

```
final short x = 10;
final short y = 3;
short z = x * y;
```

Answer (score 4):

Eso es porque Java promueve el tipo de dato de la expresión al entender que la multiplicación de dos `short` podría superar el rango para `short`.

Así que el resultado de `x * y` es un entero, que entiendo que es el error que te está dando, que no puedes asignar directamente un entero en el `short z` sin hacer un cast.

La solución, y siempre que sepas que los valores a multiplicar no superan en tamaño de un `short`, sería hacer un cast:

```
short z = (short)(x*y);
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta.
Lo que me extraña es que no me dé error en:
short x = 10;
short y = 3; 
ya que los literales por defecto son int. En cambio me da error en la tercera línea realizando la misma conversión.